# Write out the operator (A)^2 for A = (d/dx + x)

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-operators

I am having difficulties understanding how this operator is multiplied out. I have the answer, but do not know why (see below) it is what it is. Imagine there is a carat (^) above the "A" for correct notation.

Write out the operator $(A)^2$ for

$$A = (d/dx + x)$$

This [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOfnC.jpg) is the solution to the problem.

What I am confused about is where did $f(x) \cdot dx/dx$ come from? Also, why does $d/dx \cdot xf(x)$ turn into $x \cdot[df(x)/dx]$, not $[d(f(x) \cdot x)/dx]$? Please explain. Thanks!

Comment: Have you also tried to *write out yourself* the double application of $A$ for a function $f$ instead of only reading it?

Comment: It sounds like the applied the product rule to expand $D(f(x)x)$.

Comment: yes but I haven't gotten the answer given from the solution manual (linked)

Comment: StrangerLoop.. thanks, you solved my misunderstanding (it's been a few years since i've taken a calculus class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your confusion stems from the application of the product rule, which is generally:
$$\frac{d}{dx}(u\cdot v) = \frac{du}{dx} \cdot v + u \cdot \frac{dv}{dx}$$

In your case it is:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\Big(x\cdot f(x)\Big) = \frac{dx}{dx} \cdot f(x) + x \cdot \frac{df(x)}{dx}$$